# Django and nosetests : DoesNotExist: <object> matching query does not exist

Tags: django, matching

I'm just starting a small app on django. Its aim, for now, is just to manage testers (aka users) and teams. here's my model.py :

```
from django.db import models

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_testers(self):
        return self.tester_set.all()

class Tester(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    visa = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    privileged = models.BooleanField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.visa
```

I'm trying to write a test for the "get_testers" function.
Here it is :

```
from models import Team, Tester
def testTeamGetTesters_test():
    t = list(Team.objects.get(id=2L).get_testers())

    a = Tester(visa = 'a', privileged = True)
    b = Tester(visa = 'b', privileged = True)

    assert(t[0].visa == a.visa and t[0].privileged == a.privileged and t[1].visa == b.visa and t[1].privileged == b.privileged)
```

But when I run :

```
$ python manage.py test tmg
```

I get this error :

```
nosetests --verbosity 1 tmg
E
======================================================================
ERROR: tempsite.tmg.tests.testTeamGetTesters_test
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/nose/case.py", line 183, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/home/charlie/code/tempsite/../tempsite/tmg/tests.py", line 8, in testTeamGetTesters_test
    t = list(Team.objects.get(id=2L).get_testers())
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/manager.py", line 132, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/query.py", line 341, in get
    % self.model._meta.object_name)
DoesNotExist: Team matching query does not exist.
```

So, I wrote just about the same test, but directly runable :

```
from models import Team, Tester

t = list(Team.objects.get(id=2L).get_testers())

a = Tester(visa = 'a', privileged = True)
b = Tester(visa = 'b', privileged = True)

print "%r" % (t[0].visa == a.visa and t[0].privileged == a.privileged and t[1].visa == b.visa and t[1].privileged == b.privileged)
```

...And when I run it :

```
$ python tests.py
True
```

This is very confusing... I checked the database, the objects are all perfectly retrieved, but I still get this error...

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating the Team object with id 2 somewhere in your test? Don't forget tests start with a blank database.